# PowerShell - sending mail script throwing error

Tags: email, powershell

Here is the Powershell  Script code i am using

```
$SmtpClient = New-Object system.net.mail.smtpClient;
$mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage;
$SmtpClient.Host = "exchange server name";
$SmtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("User name", "password");
$mailmessage.from = ("user@domain.com");
$mailmessage.To.add("user@domain.com");
$mailmessage.Subject = “Message”;
$mailmessage.Body = “Body”;
$smtpclient.Send($mailmessage);
```

Here is the error  i am getting

> Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
>   At C:\Users\user1\Desktop\sendmailPS.ps1:9 char:17
>   + $smtpclient.Send <<<< ($mailmessage);
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationExcept     ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Any Help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: It may be connector permssions on the Exchange server.  Are you sure that server will do smtp relay?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a need to maintain compatibility with PowerShell 1.0, use `send-mailmessage` instead. Linebreaks added for readability.

```
send-mailmessage -smtphost your.smtp.host -from user@domain.com -to user@domain.com `
-subject "message" -body "body" `
-Credential (New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`
     -ArgumentList "user name" (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force))
```

Comment: Thanks for this! didn't know I could use Mail-message, much better.